# Django Braces' "JSONResponseMixin" shows weird behavior

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to use the "JSONResponseMixin" from the Django-braces package.

**The mixin:**

```
class JSONResponseMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin that allows you to easily serialize simple data such as a dict or
    Django models.
    """
    content_type = u"application/json"
    json_dumps_kwargs = None

    def get_content_type(self):
        if self.content_type is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                u"%(cls)s is missing a content type. "
                u"Define %(cls)s.content_type, or override "
                u"%(cls)s.get_content_type()." % {
                u"cls": self.__class__.__name__}
            )
        return self.content_type

    def get_json_dumps_kwargs(self):
        if self.json_dumps_kwargs is None:
            self.json_dumps_kwargs = {}
        self.json_dumps_kwargs.setdefault(u'ensure_ascii', False)
        return self.json_dumps_kwargs

    def render_json_response(self, context_dict, status=200):
        """
        Limited serialization for shipping plain data. Do not use for models
        or other complex or custom objects.
        """
        json_context = json.dumps(context_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder,
                                  **self.get_json_dumps_kwargs())
        return HttpResponse(json_context,
                            content_type=self.get_content_type(),
                            status=status)

    def render_json_object_response(self, objects, **kwargs):
        """
        Serializes objects using Django's builtin JSON serializer. Additional
        kwargs can be used the same way for django.core.serializers.serialize.
        """
        json_data = serializers.serialize(u"json", objects, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type=self.get_content_type())
```

I am basically inheriting this mixin into my own view to return a JSON response to javascript call back function.

Here is my view:

**views.py**

```
class PostDetail(JSONResponseMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail_page.html'
```

So this is a really really simple view... yet when I open this view, weird thing happens. The page shows plain html source code instead of rendering the source into html page. Of course, this doesn't happen once I remove the JSONResponseMixin inheritance in my view. I have no idea why this is happening, since JSONResponseMixin doesn't directly override the "render_to_response" method or anything important....

Can someone tell me why this is happening..? Thanks!!!

**Btw, this is the resulting html page:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link title="Wrap Long Lines" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet">
        #HAVE NO IDEA WHERE THIS CAME FROM...
    </head>

    <body>
        #ALL MY HTML SOURCE CODE APPEARS HERE WITHOUT BEING RENDERED!!!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the content type for the response is "application/json" by default. It's not going to render your template as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
content_type = u"application/json"
```

This line is actually used by `DetailView`. My best guess is that this messed up your template's rendering; either by using `"application/json"` or by not supplying a charset.

I would leave the default content_type alone (use `content_type = None`) and override `get_content_type` to supply the content type you need when using Ajax.

To fully incorporate JSON into your view, you should probably overwrite `render_to_response` on your `PostDetail` view:

```
class PostDetail(JSONResponseMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail_page.html'
    content_type = None

    def render_to_response(self, **kwargs):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            # Don't really know if objects will take a list, a queryset, any iterable or even a single object
            return self.render_json_object_response(objects=[self.object]):
        else:
            return super(PostDetail, self).render_to_response(**kwargs)

    def get_content_type(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return u'application/json'
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: Actually you were right!!! Once I put the "content_type=None," the problem disappeared :)) Yet I'm not really sure how I should override the get_content_type method appropriately...

Comment: I'm guessing it would be something like..."if self.request.is_ajax(): return u'application/json' " in get_content_type??

Comment: Actually, considering you only use `get_content_type` on an Ajax request, you can just do `def get_content_type(self): return u'application/json'`.

Comment: @user2492270 Actually, scrap that. I've updated my answer with a proper implementation, as what you had wouldn't ever respond with the JSON data.

Comment: There has to be a better fix than this. Overwriting each view with JSONResponseMixin is quite annoying.

Comment: You can put this code in a `MixedDetailView` class and subclass that class instead for your actual view.